# python How can I fix OpenCV cvtColor error?

Tags: python, opencv

Here is the erroneous code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640) 
cap.set(4,480) 
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, -1) 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
   k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: 
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/piwheels/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:10638: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you display the frame right after capture without any processing? I suspect your camera doesn’t support the set size so cap.read() returns an error.

Comment: I think the frame is already 1 channel (Gray) and when you trying to convert it to COLOR_BGR2GRAY it doesn't find the 3 channels expected and raise the error.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked fine. Can you try printing the type of frame and see the number of channels?

Comment: In python, `print frame.shape` should be able to give dimensions of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

What the error message say is that your input image to cvtColor (frame) should have either three (R, G, B) or four (R, G, B, A) channels to convert it to grayscale, and it does not.

This can happen because:

1. Your camera does not capture an image at all
2. It captures the image in grayscale

First, comment the lines

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

and

```
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
```

and test if you can see the captured frames. Most likely you won't see color images, and that (image capture) could be where the problem is.